# converting STL model to osg format

Tags: c++, openscenegraph

I want to convert STL model to osg format using visual studio c++ and openSceneGraph
can any one help me
Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the research you have already done?

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Assimp](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/index.html) to convert model formats. It can input .stl and output .obj files.